# Recommended place for a Django project to live on Linux

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I'm uploading  my first Django project to a Linux server, where I should put my project in the filesystem?

With a PHP, or ASP project, everything goes into `/var/www`, would it be ok to do the same and add my Django project to the `/var/www` folder?

Comment: How will you serve django? wsgi? gunicorn etc?

Comment: I will service it with wsgi plugin.

Comment: I use /srv/wsgi/site or /var/wsgi/site when on a debian-system.

Comment: I simply use `/sites/foo/`, `/sites/bar/` (each is a `virtualenv`)

Comment: There is no answer to this question. It's linux, it goes where you need it to go. I put mine in /var/django. Put it wherever it makes the most sense/is the most secure.

Comment: what permissions do you need to set for the directory with the django files to be accessible to the server?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project) it states:

> Where should this code live?
> If your background is in PHP, you're probably used to putting code under the Web server's document root (in a place such as /var/www). With Django, you don't do that. It's not a good idea to put any of this Python code within your Web server's document root, because it risks the possibility that people may be able to view your code over the Web. That's not good for security.
>
> Put your code in some directory outside of the document root, such as **/home/mycode**.

Comment: Normally all folders in /home/ are users' home folders. So should I create a user called "mycode", or are they talking about *just* creating a folder.

Comment: @MadsSkjern they are talking about creating a directory (folder) on the server, in the home of the user the server runs as. (Being in the home folder means the content (the code) will not be public to the world.)

Comment: I've noticed that the default Apache DocumentRoot (Ubuntu 14.04) is now `/var/www/html`. Does this mean that it's now safe to create Django projects under `/var/www`?

Comment: @user3817250 No! The point is you want this in the user's home directory because this **not** visible to the web. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot

Comment: @AndyHayden If the global Apache DocumentRoot is `/var/www/html` then `/var/www/djangoproject` shouldn't be visible to the web unless you explicitly define it as the DocumentRoot of a VirtualHost? I don't like the idea of scattering websites across multiple directories. I'd much rather be able to put my php sites alongside my django sites.

Comment: I've put a django project under my home directory ~/mysite with a socket ~/mysite/mysite/mysite.sock , but now nginx can't write to that socket.  Now I see a recommendation "You may also have to add your user to nginx’s group (which is probably www-data), or vice-versa, so that nginx can read and write to your socket properly." but surely that has negative security implications as well.

Answer (score 5):

## File Hierarchy System

@Andy Hayden really states where not to place ones code. The [File Hierarchy System (FHS)](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.pdf) implicates the following structure; `PATH` maps to `PACKAGE` or `PROVIDER` (It is recommended that parties providing multiple packages should use `PROVIDER/PACKAGE`) :

```
/etc/opt/PATH  # FHS location for /opt configuration files
/opt/PATH      # FHS location for PROVIDER or PACKAGE name
/var/opt/PATH  # FHS location for /opt variable storage
```

The FHS expects `/opt/PATH` to contain all the material necessary for the successful execution of ones package so it seems prudent to setup the following symbolic links

- `/etc/opt/PATH` to `/opt/PATH/etc`
- `/var/opt/PATH` to `/opt/PATH/var`

This provides a good basis but Django projects have extraneous requirements that the above structure does not fully meet.

### Static Files

Static files are deployed when one runs `python manage.py collectstatic` to the `STATIC_ROOT` which should point to the web server root for static delivery, usually `/var/www/PATH`.

One could link  `/var/www/PATH` symbolically to `/opt/PATH/static` 
but this is typically a bad idea; Consider the case that you have a misconfigured server and a user goes to `www.domain.tld/../` and copies your work.

### Settings

If you created your project with `django-admin create-project WEBSITE` the you will typically have a `setup.py` file under the `WEBSITE` folder.

```
PROJECT/
    WEBSITE/
         setup.py
         ...
```

If you converted this settings module into a package, or you used some wrapper around `django-admin` e.g. `django-cms-create` etc.

```
PROJECT/
    WEBSITE/
         settings/
             __init__.py  # from .settings import *
             settings.py
         ...
```

You might symlink `/etc/opt/PATH` to `/opt/PATH/WEBSITE/settings` instead of `/opt/PATH/etc` as described above. I can't think of a practical reason for doing so though... YMMV.

### Media

Media, typically provided by ones websites users, are placed into  `MEDIA_ROOT`. It seems prudent to map `/var/opt/PATH` to `/opt/PATH/media` in this case.

### Virtual Environments

`/opt/PATH/env` seems the most logical location. `/var/env/PATH` also seems sensible but is probably better suited as a symbolic link to `/opt/PATH/env`.

Since a virtual environment is neither an application nor a library the locations `/opt/bin` and `/opt/libs` would not do for this. `/env/` or `/pyvenv/` does not conform to the FHS.

### Whiskey

If you're using `mod_wsgi` with Apache the an invocation similar to [`python manage.py runmodwsgi --server-root /etc/opt/PATH --setup-only`](https://youtu.be/H6Q3l11fjU0?t=624) is probably preferable since it places the Apache control commands into the FHS compliant locations, granted they are more cumbersome to invoke in this case.

### Home

To my understanding `/home` was traditionally used by PHP developers when they were hosting multiple sites upon the same server. If you're using Django you're probably serving your site from a dedicated machine and this structure looses a bit of favour in this case... YMMV.